# Google Play update error apk

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-update-app

I have loaded an app to Google Play 3 months ago. it is my first time so I have create many apk so I now have my app code. But When I click Generate Signed APK,

Android studio gives me :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file /Users/berkay/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/SosyalAlarm/app/app-release.apk not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.``
```

I have updated my version at gradle. How can I update my app ?

Comment: Check your '**keystore.jks**' file, you maybe misplaced the path. Also check the keystore path where it is generated for the first time, usually you can find it in "***C:\Users\.android***".

Comment: Yes I have  found 3 jks files. (It "s name is my_android_app_name.jks ). I have created many times because I had too many problem. What I do now ?

Comment: Did you check your **keystore.jks** file and its path?

Comment: Sorry about lately my answer. I was working on problem my app. Yes. I found it.What I will do now?

Comment: Anyone can help me ?